# Left invariant vector field and Tangent space at $e$ on a Lie group $G$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-space-isomorphism

I have to say sorry about my English which is not my native language. So you can ask me for the ambiguous concepts of what I wrote.

Notation: $(G,\cdot)$is a Lie group, $\mathscr{L}$ is left invariant vector field on $G$ and  $T_eG$ is tangent space at $e\in G$.

I read a theorem that said $\mathscr{L}$ and $T_eG$ are linearly isomorphic to each other. That is

$$\exists \  \text{an isomorphism}\ \eta:T_eG \rightarrow\mathscr{L} \ \text{s.t.}\ A\mapsto\eta(A)\equiv \bar{A} $$
Where $A\in T_eG$ is a vector and $\bar{A} \in \mathscr{L}$ is a vector field.

**Question1**: Elements of $T_eG$ are vectors and elements of $\mathscr{L}$ are a vector fields. Why can we map a vector to a vector field?(Is this allowed?)

I mean in the proof we define that
$$\forall A\in T_eG, \text{Define} \ \bar{A}|_g:=L_{g*}A, \ \forall g \in G$$
Where $L_{g*}$ is a push forward of left translation and   $\bar{A}|_g$ is a vector and $\bar{A}|_g\notin\mathscr{L}$ (because $\bar{A}|_g $is a vector not vector field.)
So it is not reasonable for me to say $A\mapsto\eta(A)\equiv \bar{A}$, and $A\mapsto\eta(A)\equiv \bar{A}|_g, \forall g \in G$ is more reasonable for me.

**Question2**:So I collection all of  $\bar{A}|_g$ be a vector field  $\mathscr{L}’$(also a vector space)(I don’t know which one is better of I described.)
$$\mathscr{L}’:=\{\bar{A}\in\mathscr{L}|\bar{A}|_g=L_{g*}A,g\in G, \ A \in T_eG   \}$$
$$\mathscr{L}':=\{\bar{A}_g \ |\ \bar{A}|_g=L_{g*}A, g\in G , A\in T_eG \}$$
Therefore, I may say $T_eG$ and $\mathscr{L}’$ are linear isomorphic to each other (use $\mathscr{L}’$ to instead of $\mathscr{L}$ ) is reasonable for me.

**Question3**: Are $\mathscr{L}’$ and $\mathscr{L}$ equivalent or not?

**Conclusion**: For me

Vector($T_eG$) maps to another vector ($\mathscr{L}’$) by $\eta$ is reasonable  for me.

Vector($T_eG$) maps to a vector field($\mathscr{L}$) by $\eta$ is not reasonable for me.

Again,

Thanks for reading and answering my question. Sorry for wasting your time and my poor English .

Hopefully I have explained  enough to let you understand my question as possible as I can.

Answer (score 5):

(For technical reasons let's assume $G$ is connected.) To answer your question, let me first explain a little more about left invariant fields. Let's start with two things.

- Choose some element $g \in G$. Since $G$ is a Lie group, then I get a left translation map $\ell_g: G \to G$ given by $h \mapsto gh$. (You can think of this intuitively as "pushing" $h$ to $gh$.)
- A vector field $X$ on $G$ is a function $X: G \to \mathsf{T}G$ that gives you a tangent vector $X_h \in \mathsf{T}_hG$ above each point $h \in G$. (You can think of this as a bunch of arrows placed over $G$.)

Now I can push $X$ forward by $\ell_g$, to obtain a new vector field $(\ell_g)_*X$ as follows. Given a point $h \in G$, I need to define a vector $((\ell_g)_*X)_h \in \mathsf{T}_hX$ in the tangent space above $h$. To do this, let me start at the point $g^{-1}h \in G$. The translation map $\ell_g$ sends $g^{-1}h \mapsto h$, so its derivative $\mathsf{d}(\ell_g)_{g^{-1}h}$ at $g^{-1}h$ is a function $\mathsf{T}_{g^{-1}h}G \to \mathsf{T}_hG$. So if I take the tangent vector $X_{g^{-1}h} \in \mathsf{T}_{g^{-1}h}G$, then I can push it forward by this derivative to get a vector in $\mathsf{T}_hX$, which is what I wanted. In other words, I define
$$
((\ell_g)_*X)_h := \mathsf{d}(\ell_g)_{g^{-1}h}(X_{g^{-1}h}).
$$
So I've started at the point $g^{-1}h$ and "pushed" the vector $X_{g^{-1}h}$ over to the tangent space $\mathsf{T}_hG$ to get a vector $((\ell_g)_*X)_h$ above $h$. However, *there's no reason that this new vector $((\ell_g)_*X)_h$ has to be the equal to the vector $X_h$ that was already there.* The original vector field could be changing in totally different ways over $G$. But if $X$ is left invariant, then by the definition of a left invariant vector field, we have exactly
$$
X_h = ((\ell_g)_*X)_h.
$$
In other words, if $X$ is left invariant, then *as long as I know the value of my vector field $X$ at some point of $G$, then I can find the value of $X$ anywhere else just by pushing it forward by the correct translation map.* So all of the information you need about the left invariant vector field can be recovered by its value at a single point.

So, if you give me a single tangent vector $A \in \mathsf{T}_eG$, then I can just create an entire vector field $\bar{A}$ on $G$ by defining its value at each point $g \in G$ to be $\bar{A}_g := d(\ell_g)_e(A)$. That is, I'm taking the vector $A$ and pushing it over to $g$ using the map $d(\ell_g)_e: \mathsf{T}_eG \to \mathsf{T}_gG$. By construction, this vector field is left invariant. So I've just defined a function
$$
\eta: \mathsf{T}_eG \to \mathscr{L}, \quad A \mapsto \eta(A) := \bar{A},
$$
assigning a left invariant vector *field* to every vector $A \in \mathsf{T}_eG$. This is definitely allowed! Defining the inverse of $\eta$ is easy. Given a left invariant vector field $X \in \mathscr{L}$, just send it to its value at $e$. That is, define $\eta^{-1}: \mathscr{L} \mapsto \mathsf{T}_eG$ by $X \mapsto X_e$.

To answer your second question, firstly I think you may be confusing the collection $\{\bar{A}_g\}_{g \in G}$ (the values of a *single* vector field, at each point of $G$) with the collection $\mathscr{L}$ of *all* left invariant vector fields $A$ on $G$. The first one, you can think of as a vector field (though it's better to think of a vector field as a function $G \to \mathsf{T}G$). The second one is a vector space. Next, yes, $\mathscr{L}'$ is isomorphic to $\mathsf{T}_eG$ as a vector space; that's because we've defined an isomorphism $\eta$ between them.

For your last question, you've essentially defined the space $\mathscr{L}' = \{ \bar{A} = \eta(A) \mid A \in \mathsf{T}_eG \}$ as the *image* of $\eta$. That is, you took all of the vectors in $\mathsf{T}_eG$ and collected the vector fields that $\eta$ sends them to into a set. Again, every one of these vector fields is left invariant, so what you've defined is a subset $\mathscr{L}'\subset\mathscr{L}$. But actually, $\mathscr{L}'=\mathscr{L}$ because, as we've seen above, *every* left invariant field $X$ is in the image of $\eta$, since $X = \eta(X_e)$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very thanks for answering my question and I will read you answer carefully. If I have any more question I will leave the question in here. Very thank you!